# How to use Java servlet as my backend using a Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, backend, java-server

I have developed a Flex application. I have also developed a Java servlet program for an Access database using Tomcat. How can I use that servlet backend for my Flex application using HTTPService (or anything else)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these links will be of help:

[Flex with Java Servlets: how to use XML from an HttpService to populate a Data Grid(Table)](http://www.devrecipes.com/2009/04/20/flex-with-java-servlets-how-to-use-xml-from-an-httpservice-to-populate-a-data-gridtable/)
[Getting Java and Flex talking via XML](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=604)